# How to filter journalctl logs by human readable facility?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-journald, journalctl

I can do the following to get local3 logs:

```
journalctl SYSLOG_FACILITY=19
```

The magic number 19 is uterly confusing. How can I do the following:

```
journalctl WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE=local3
```

?

I do not see anything helpful in man `journalctl` or `journalct -n10 -ojson | jq | less`.

Comment: It's probably not possible, but keep in mind that the syslog facilities are standardized. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog.

Comment: Syslog been with us for 30 years, it is standardized. One more reason a command like journalctl could support it. Maybe there is a `$(translate_syslog local3)` command, like `errno ENOTSUP` from moreutils?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not see anything helpful in man journalctl

There is a `--facility` option:

```
journalctl --facility=local3
```